# Autocmd for hard wrap and going back to the previous position!

Tags: vimrc

In my .vimrc file I have

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.c :g/./ normal gqq
```

with text width 119 in order to hardwrap the lines before saving the buffer.

I tried

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.c :g/./ normal gqq``zz
```

to move the cursor back to where it was and bring it in the centre but it seems like taking me to some arbitary location.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Other issues aside, it would be more robust to set a mark explicitly and jump to that, IMO.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: If you want to mark whatever the currrent line is before the global command is run, for instance, then `kx | exe ':g/./ ... etc' | normal 'xzz`

Comment: Note that I arbitrarily chose `x` for the mark. Use whatever you want. (You could even use, believe it or not, ` ... though I'd probably avoid it to prevent confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

What your command does ``` :g/./ normal gqq``zz ``` is "for each line do normal command which is format line and goto last position and recenter.

What you have to do is to separate `:g/../normal gqq` command and the rest.

Smth like (tested) ``` exe ':g/./normal gqq' | normal ``zz ```

1. `exe` is to execute a string as a command (`:h execute`)
2. `|` is to add another command to the line
3. `normal` to execute normal mode commands from command mode :)

So the end result should be (not tested)

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.c :exe ':g/./normal gqq' | normal ``zz
```